# ArgumentError ( is not a valid ) by enum

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### Overview

When creating a form (checkbox) using enum,

```
ArgumentError ('1' is not a valid brake):
```

Error occurred

This column only accepts integers,reject '1'(string)
Please tell me how to convert a string to an integer.

We would appreciate it if you could lend us the wisdom of an expert.

rails '6.0.3'

### debug

The contents of param when the form is skipped(there is also the character string "1" ...)

```
(byebug) params
<ActionController::Parameters {"authenticity_token"=>"...", "brake"=>"1", "controller"=>"download", "action"=>"confirm"} permitted: false>
```

### code

download.rb

```
class Download < ApplicationRecord
    enum brake: {on: 1, off: 0}, _prefix: true
end
```

download_controller.rb

```
class download_controller < ApplicationController

    SESSION_KEY_FOR_DOWNLOAD = :download

    def new
        @download = ::Download.new
    end

    def confirm
        parameters = download_params
        @download = ::Download.new(parameters)
        session[SESSION_KEY_FOR_DOWNLOAD] = parameters
    end

    def create
        @download = ::Download.new(session[SESSION_KEY_FOR_DOWNLOAD])
        @download.save
        session[SESSION_KEY_FOR_DOWNLOAD] = nil
        redirect_to root_url
    end


    def download_params
        params.permit(:brake )
    end

end
```

new.html.erb

```
<%= form_with url: confirm_download_path(@download), local: true do |f| %>
  <fieldset class="form_check-block">
    <label>
      <%= f.check_box :brake, checked: @download&.brake_on? %>
      <%= f.label " ", class: "top_left" %>
    </label>
  </fieldset>
  <span>brake</span>
  <button>register</button>
<% end %>
```

shema.rb

```
  create_table "download", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "brake", limit: 1, default: 1, null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end
```

Comment: You can just transform the value of the hash for the key `brake`, but why are you using data from the session instead of using the data coming from the params after sending the form?

Comment: Could you please accept the answer @katahik? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you are using a checkbox (only two states) with an enum might highlight a design flaw.
You should consider the following changes:

- keep the checkbox and use a boolean column for the `brake` attribute
- use select field and keep the `brake` enum (if you plan to have more states)

If you want to keep the checkbox and the enum, you need to refer to the possible values of `brake` by name and not by value

```rb
f.check_box :brake, { checked: @download&.brake_on? }, :on, :off
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.check_box :brake, checked: @download&.brake_on? %>
↓
<%= f.check_box :brake, { checked: @download&.brake_on? }, :on, :off %>
```